# How can a fault tolarent Distributed Data Saving Algorithm can be developed?

Tags: error-correcting-codes, algorithm-design

I am trying to design an algorithm. For now, I am trying to give myself a large overview.

Assume I have `K` (for example, `K` can equal 8) perfect slave machines, and one master machine. Each slave has a perfect HDD. I want to save the string "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP".  My wished are

1. I want to only save a fragment of the string to each HDD belonging to an unique slave
2. I want to make sure, that an adversary can only recover the full string, if and only if he can access at least `P` fraction of the slaves (for example, `P` can be 50%).
3. However, an authorized user can recover the complete string, even if a few slaves are offline, or not accessible. Let's call the number of offline slaves `n`, let's also assume that `n < PK`. For example, in this case `n` can be 2, which is less than 50% of 8 total slaves.

Note that I am differentiating between compromised and accessible. A prefect adversary compromises a slave without rendering it accessible. However, a slave can become inaccessible with or without the involvement of an adversary.

How should I go about designing an algorithm that can do it?

**My attempt to solution** was to experiment with Reed Solomon Encoding - but I can't find a way that would allow both the fault tolerance, and significant difficulty for an attacker.

As an answer, I would like a detailed pseudocode with explanation with step by step explanation.  In this question, I have not set any limit on `K` or `p` because I don't know if that is necessary or not. However, if a fully general answer isn't possible, then may be you can set suitable limits on these, to develop a special solution.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [secret sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secret_sharing).  With a $k$-out-of-$n$ secret sharing scheme, the string is distributed among $n$ "slaves".  Access to any $k$ "slaves" is enough to recover the string; but with access to $k-1$ or fewer "slaves", an adversary cannot learn anything about the string.

There are many standard secret sharing schemes in the literature.  For instance, you can use [Shamir secret sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shamir%27s_secret_sharing).